# Материалы по css хакам

Tags: css

Посоветуйте что-нибудь почитать хорошее по css. Мой уровень: читал книжки, смотрел курсы, сверстал макетов 10 по psd, всё это было в основном до выхода css3. Из него использую только flex и border-radius. 
Хотелось бы почитать что нибудь толковое и техническое по css, например, верстал вчера горизонтальное двухуровневое меню.

```
<li>
 <a>
 <ul>...</ul>
</li>
```

Для ul примерно следующие стили:

```
position:absolute;
display:none;
left:0;
top:100%
```

Всё хорошо, только вот у li в ul'е высота 0 px. Интересно почему

Comment: https://webref.ru/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что ul задан display: none. Это значит, что его не существует в потоке документа. Следовательно, li - пустой элемент, поэтому и не имеет высоты. Почитать советую http://htmlbook.ru

Comment: Ну так при ховере на li я ul'у присваиваю display:block.

Comment: @Эдуард приведите полный пример кода.

Comment: @Эдуард добавьте код к вашему вопросу и сделайте его исполняемым.

Comment: ааа, разобрался, потому что внутри ли лежит ссылка, а у неё float:left стоит. Спасибо за подсказки

Comment: @Эдуард если помогло - проголосуйте за мой ответ.

Comment: @Эдуард выберите лучший ответ.